# Error in using WEKA SVM Model in my java code (Empty SVM model after saving it in WEKA)

Tags: java, android, svm, weka, libsvm

I have trained LIBSVM model in WEKA (3.7.3) and now want to use it in my java code. However, I'm getting an exception.

```
Exception:Attempt to invoke interface method 'double weka.classifiers.Classifier.classifyInstance(weka.core.Instance)' on a null object reference
```

All other models work fine in this java code. Moreover, the version of WEKA jar is exactly the same as I'm using for training models. I don't have any LIBSVM jar in my app because I'm using the trained model. Do I need to place LIBSVM jar in my app ?

What am I missing here ?

```
     inputStream = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open("svm.model");
     classifier = (Classifier) weka.core.SerializationHelper.read(inputStream);
```

This is the content of the model:

```
=== Model information ===

Filename:     svm.model
Scheme:       weka.classifiers.functions.LibSVM -S 0 -K 2 -D 3 -G 0.0 -R 0.0 -N 0.5 -M 40.0 -C 1.0 -E 0.001 -P 0.1 -model "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\Weka-3-7" -seed 1
Relation:     Sho_gsw30SVRNULL-weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.Remove-R5-13,18-26,31-39,44-130
Attributes:   17
              F1
              F2
              F3
              F4
              F14
              F15
              F16
              F17
              F27
              F28
              F29
              F30
              F40
              F41
              F42
              F43
              class

=== Classifier model ===

LibSVM wrapper, original code by Yasser EL-Manzalawy (= WLSVM)
```

**Update:** 
I tried WEKA SMO (support vector machine classifier) and it works fine in my code, but not the LIBSVM one.

Comment: Show us the code where you call `classifyInstance`

Comment: @Sentry code is added to the original question.

Comment: It seems like `classifier` is `null`, so loading it using the SerializationHelper goes wrong. Hard to say from distance what is the cause. Can you check if the file "svm.model" exists and if it contains a valid model?

Comment: @Sentry you may be right. The model file exists, but when I try to reload it in WEKA, there are only features but nothing else. Seems like WEKA is not saving the model properly ? I just updated the content of the model here. I would assume that its a problem on WEKA side then rather than the java or android.

Comment: I attempted an answer

Comment: you can follow steps shown in this anwer to create your classifier http://stackoverflow.com/a/40236792/3923800. As @Sentry pointed out the model should not be human readable.

Comment: @xro7 I created the same serialized model in WEKA (GUI) which uses the same underlying code i guess.

Comment: Weka uses Java serialization. By design serialized classes can only be deserialized in the same environment. Therefore training on J2SE and loading on Android will most likely fail because they are completely different (Android bases on Apache harmony).

Comment: @Robert I'm using a WEKA jar which has been adopted for Android (by commenting out things which won't work with Android). All other models' serialization/de-serialization works fine except LIBSVM.

Comment: @zub12: Yes, but the used JRE is different, which means that the internal field names may differ. May be you should switch to Weka XML serailization.

Comment: @Robert Okay, I'll check on how to serialize the svm classifier using xml method and will update then.  I still wonder though why would I observe the problem with one specific classifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I tried WEKA SMO (support vector machine classifier) and it works fine in my code, but not the LIBSVM one.

Answer (score 1):

If what you've shown as the content of your model is the actual content of the "svm.model" file, then that is the culprit.

Model files in WEKA are serialized Java objects. They can be created by training a classifier, which is equivalent to the model, and [serializing that Java WEKA classifier object into a file](https://weka.wikispaces.com/Serialization). The file will probably NOT be human readable.

Here is code for serializing a model based on the WEKA site I linked:

```
// classifier will be your SVM classifier here
// and instances the training instances
classifier.buildClassifier(instances); 

// serialize model
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(
                         new FileOutputStream("svm.model"));
oos.writeObject(classifier);
oos.flush();
oos.close();
```

That model can then be loaded and used by the code you've posted in your question.

Comment: I understand that it may not be human readable. However, there is no information at all in the saved model of SVM. I used SMO classifier of WEKA which also implements the support vector machines but there are information about the model. When I load a trained SMO classifier, it contains information about the model in it, however, the LIBSVM classifier is empty. Saving model in WEKA means that its serialized. I used the same method with other classifiers and they work fine in my code. So problem seems to be with saving libsvm model in weka.

Comment: What Weka version are you using and where did you get the LibSVM classifier for Weka? Those might also be good information to add to the original question.

Comment: I have added weka version. There is only one version of libsvm for weka which comes with WEKA.

Comment: I've worked mainly with Weka 3.6 and for that I had to download LibSVM separately. I'll check it out and see if I can find anything useful.

Comment: thanks. Yes, that used be the case with 3.6 but not anymore since 3.7 i guess.

Comment: Sorry for this taking so long, I hope I will get to it this weekend.

Comment: Okay, so I installed Weka 3.7.3 and I tried to use the GUI to train a LibSVM. I can't even get that to work because of some bugs in their code. How exactly did you create your model file?

Comment: I used Weka 3.7.3 (GUI based) and its working fine with me.  May be you should reinstall it.  I created the model file using GUI.