# How to use created model with new data in Weka

Tags: java, weka

I'm trying some tests on weka, hope someone can help me and i can made myself clear.

**Step 1: Tokenize my data**

```
@attribute text string
@attribute @@class@@ {derrota,empate,win}

@data
'O Grêmio perdeu para o Cruzeiro por 1 a 0',derrota
'O Grêmio venceu o Palmeiras em um grande jogo de futebol, nesta quarta-feira na Arena',vitoria
```

**Step 2: Build model on tokenized data**

After loading this i apply a StringToWordVector. After applying this filter i save a new arff file with the words tokenized. Something like..

```
@attribute @@class@@ {derrota,vitoria,win}
@attribute o numeric
@attribute grêmio numeric
@attribute perdeu numeric
@attribute venceu numeric
@ and so on .....

@data
{0 derrota, 1 1, 2 1, 3 1, 4 0, ...}
{0 vitoria, 1 1, 2 1, 3 0, 4 1, ...}
```

Ok! Now based on this arff i build my classifier model and save it.

**Step 3: Test with "simulated new data"**

If i want to test my model with "simulated new data" what im doing actually is editing this last arff and making a line like

{0 ?, 1 1, 2 1, 3 1, 4 0, ...}

**Step 4(my problem): How to test with really new data**

So far so good. My problem is when i need to use this model with 'really' new data.
For example, if i have a string with "O Grêmio caiu diante do Palmeiras". I have 4 new words that doesn't exist in my model and 2 that exist.

How can i create a arff file with this new data that can be fitted in my model? (ok i know that the 4 new words will not be present, but how can i work with this?)

After supply a different test data the following message appears

[image]

Comment: are you using Weka GUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Weka programmatically then you can do this fairly easy.

- Create your training file (e.g training.arff)
- Create Instances from training file. `Instances trainingData = ..`
- Use **StringToWordVector** to transform your string attributes to number representation:

*sample code:*

```
    StringToWordVector() filter = new StringToWordVector(); 
    filter.setWordsToKeep(1000000);
    if(useIdf){
        filter.setIDFTransform(true);
    }
    filter.setTFTransform(true);
    filter.setLowerCaseTokens(true);
    filter.setOutputWordCounts(true);
    filter.setMinTermFreq(minTermFreq);
    filter.setNormalizeDocLength(new SelectedTag(StringToWordVector.FILTER_NORMALIZE_ALL,StringToWordVector.TAGS_FILTER));
    NGramTokenizer t = new NGramTokenizer();
    t.setNGramMaxSize(maxGrams);
    t.setNGramMinSize(minGrams);    
    filter.setTokenizer(t);  
    WordsFromFile stopwords = new WordsFromFile();
    stopwords.setStopwords(new File("data/stopwords/stopwords.txt"));
    filter.setStopwordsHandler(stopwords);
    if (useStemmer){
        Stemmer s = new /*Iterated*/LovinsStemmer();
        filter.setStemmer(s);
    }
    filter.setInputFormat(trainingData);
```

- Apply the filter to trainingData: `trainingData = Filter.useFilter(trainingData, filter);`
- Select a classifier to create your model

*sample code for LibLinear classifier*

```
        Classifier cls = null;
        LibLINEAR liblinear = new LibLINEAR();
        liblinear.setSVMType(new SelectedTag(0, LibLINEAR.TAGS_SVMTYPE));
        liblinear.setProbabilityEstimates(true);
        // liblinear.setBias(1); // default value
        cls = liblinear;
        cls.buildClassifier(trainingData);
```

- Save model

*sample code*

```
    System.out.println("Saving the model...");
    ObjectOutputStream oos;
    oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(path+"mymodel.model"));
    oos.writeObject(cls);
    oos.flush();
    oos.close();
```

- Create a testing file (e.g testing.arff)
- Create Instances from training file: `Instances testingData=...`
- Load classifier

*sample code*

```
Classifier myCls = (Classifier) weka.core.SerializationHelper.read(path+"mymodel.model");
```

- **Use the same StringToWordVector filter as above or create a new one for testingData, but remember to use the trainingData for this command:`filter.setInputFormat(trainingData);`** *This will keep the format of training set and will not add words that are not in training set.*
- Apply the filter to testingData: `testingData = Filter.useFilter(testingData, filter);`
- Classify!

*sample code*

```
 for (int j = 0; j < testingData.numInstances(); j++) {
    double res = myCls.classifyInstance(testingData.get(j));
 }
```

---

1. Not sure if this can be done through GUI.
2. Save and load steps are optional.

Edit: after some digging in the Weka GUI i think it is possible to do it. In the *classify* tab set your testing set at the *Supply test set* field. After that your sets should normally be incompatible. To fix this click yes in the following dialog

[image]

and you are good to go.

Comment: Hey xro7! Yes, currently im using GUI. I will try this and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: if you have any issues or if i skipped or forgot anything just let me now.

Comment: Hi xro thanks for your interest in helping me! After load my test set the same message appears but only the first part, the program doesn't ask me to use the wraper.

Comment: I finally completed your example. I never have used java(coding) with weka before, actually im a c# guy. But your example was straightforward and opened my eyes to start learning weka in a different way.. I think im getting the correct answers from my model. Now i will just digg in all this classes and methods. Thanks xro!

Comment: You probably use other weka version than me. I use 3.8.Anyways weka is faster with code than gui for some reason.And i think you can do more things using it programmatically. Glad i could help.

Comment: by the way i ve added a java tag to your question